# Convert .py to .exe with multiple dependent files

Tags: python, executable

I have converted main.py to .exe on Mac and Windows both. The converted file on Mac does not work on Windows and converted Windows file does not work on Mac OS. Any suggestions on this.
I have used auto-py-to-exe for both Operating systems.
Thanks

Comment: Executable files have completely different formats on each OS. You can't have one that works on both. I'm unclear on what your problem is…

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was asking that executables file will not work on both OS. The executable file created on Mac OS does not work on Windows OS and vice versa.